# Formulário de login retornando erro!

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-select

Tenho um form de login que retorna o seguinte **ERRO**:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'as valor FROM olmp_cadparaprova WHERE email = 'cirillosales9' at
>   line 1

Código:

```
$sql = "SELECT * senha_para_login as senha, as valor 
        FROM olmp_cadparaprova 
        WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]'";
```

Alguém sabe do que se trata?

Comment: Está faltando o `SELECT`

Comment: Poste o seu select na pergunta para podermos ajudar melhor

Comment: Cirilo, o erro ocorrido é devido a seu comando select estar incorreto, tente postar a parte do código php em que monta ele, a tela que faz a requisição dos dados de login.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * senha_para_login as senha,  as valor FROM olmp_cadparaprova WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]'";

Comment: @CirilloWallison já conseguir resolver o problema?

Comment: Não consegui ainda

Comment: @CirilloWallison o após executar a minha query continua a aparecer algum erro? o erro é o mesmo ou diferente?

Comment: Limpei o cash, erro resolvido

Comment: @CirilloWallison se a minha resposta o ajudou pode aceita-la  clicando no ✔ no lado esquerdo da mesma. Se necessitar de alguma mais ajuda avise.

Answer (score 1):

O **erro** está na escolha dos campos a mostrar a sua query está mal construída, experimente em trocar `SELECT * senha_para_login as senha, as valor`, por `SELECT *`.

Ao usar o **`*`** vai retornar todas as colunas da tabela, exemplo completo:

```
SELECT * FROM olmp_cadparaprova WHERE email='$_SESSION[email]'
```

Se pretende mostrar as linhas todas de uma tabela mais uma coluna especifica pode usar o seguinte exemplo:

```
SELECT t1.coluna AS c1, t1.* FROM tabela AS t1
```

Resultado final de acordo com as suas necessidades:

```
$sql = "SELECT t1.senha_para_login AS senha, t1.* 
        FROM olmp_cadparaprova AS t1 
        WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo visto está faltando o `SELECT campos` antes do `FROM olmp_cadparaprova WHERE email = 'cirillosales9'`

Ex.:

`SELECT campo FROM olmp_cadparaprova WHERE email = 'cirillosales9'`

`SELECT * FROM olmp_cadparaprova WHERE email = 'cirillosales9'`

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM olmp_cadparaprova WHERE email = 'cirillosales9'`